# jQuery choose file with a popup message not working

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, user-input

I'm trying to add some popup message with a message ("make sure you are uploading a PDF file) to the user when they click on `input[type=file]`

the problem is that the pop message is displayed too late. I'm getting the filesystem window before the popup message

```
    <input type="file" id="file" name="" required="required" class=" form-control">    
    $(function() {
    $("#file").on("click",function(e){
                        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function() {                           
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                                }
                            }
                        });
                    });
});
```

Can anyone help please?

[FIDDLE Here](http://jsfiddle.net/sshw8p5L/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edited**
Ok I misunderstood. I think there's no way to stop filesystem window work first(anyways maybe I'm wrong but I've tried many way).
so you should have other element and add click event to it in order to trigger the `file input` that's hidden.

```
 $(function() {
    $("input#file_fake").on("click",function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Ok: function() {                           
                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );
                    $("input#file_real").trigger('click');
                }
            }
         });         
    });   
});
```

this code I assume that you want it looks like`file input` so I add a fake file input.
here is the sample: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sshw8p5L/20/)

Comment: Not working. The popup message should be presented first, before the user can choose the file.

Answer (score 0):

write your code as below :-

```
 $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
                            modal: true,
                            buttons: {
                                Ok: function() {                           
                                    $( this ).dialog( "close" );

                                }
                            }
                        });

$("#file").on("click",function(e){
       $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog( "open" );
});
```

On click event open the dialog and put dialog code out of click event!